# Rejected request from RFC1918 IP to public server address

Tags: iis, dns, ip

I got this error when trying to setup a domain name (which get from `noip.com`)

> Rejected request from RFC1918 IP to public server address

Can you tell where this error come from?

in my local host file, I have added this entry:

```
myDomain.sytes.net          202.222.12.131
```

(This is what exactly returned from `noip.com` panel)

I had also added the Binding into IIS using Hostname and Ip Address above.

Is there some steps that were missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to add the NAT Forwarding entry in my router to forward the port 80 request to my local IP Address, and that solved the issue.